# Excel Name Manager and Not Graphing Certain Values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to graph an range of cells from the bottom of a column, in such a way that any empty values are ignored.

I can grab the cells from the bottom using name manager (`=OFFSET(Foo!$X$5,COUNT(Foo!$X:$X),0,-91,1)`), and i can create empty cells the graph treats as empty using N/A (`=IF(MOD($A6,7)=4,SUM(B4:B8),NA())`), but these do not seem to want to work together. It appears name manager errors out if anything in the range is N/A, or empty string. I am not sure of another way to populate a cell as empty, or another way to grab the bottom n cells from a column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the range name on a range that does not have NA values, like the chart labels column. Then use another range name that offsets from that. In the screenshot, the **labels** range name uses an offset formula that returns the last 5 labels in column D. The **data** range name then offsets by one column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. It's weird that a workaround is needed to do this